Let $f \in C^\infty$, $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{x} \int_{\frac{x}{2}}^{\frac{3x}{2}} f(y) dy$ $\overset{?}\implies$ $f(x)=cx$
Let $f \in C^\infty$, $f(0) = 0$ and
$f(x) = \frac{1}{x} \int_{\frac{x}{2}}^{\frac{3x}{2}} f(y) dy$
$\overset{?}\implies$ $f(x)=cx$
I started by multiplying $x$ to the lhs. This gives $f(x)x = \int_{\frac{x}{2}}^{\frac{3x}{2}} f(y) dy$. Differentiating both sides leeds to following equation: $$f(x)+f'(x)x=\frac{3}{2}f(\frac{3x}{2})-\frac{1}{2}f(\frac{x}{2})$$
It is clear that $f(x)=cx$ is a solution for the differential equation, however is it the only one? I think that solving the differential equation would leed to the solution but I am not sure how to proceed from here on. How do I solve this type of equations? Is there another way to proof that $f(x)=cx$ is the only solution?

Hi, I am not an expert in ODEs but did you differentiate both sides with respect to y or x, or does it not matter?

@hablahblahha $\int_{\frac{x}{2}}^{\frac{3x}{2}}f(y)dy$ is also a function of $x$.

Guess:Only $f(x)=kx+b(k,b\in \mathbb{R})$ satisfy the condition $f(x)x'+f'(x)x=\frac{3}{2}f(\frac{3x}{2})-\frac{1}{2}f(\frac{x}{2})$.

If f(x) is a function of x, if you differentiate both sides by x would the left hand side be f(x)+f'(x)x?

If you replace f(x) with $g(s) = f(2^s)$ this becomes a delay ODE

Let
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n. $$
Putting in
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x} \int_{\frac{x}{2}}^{\frac{3x}{2}} f(y) dy$$
gives
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{(n+1)2^{n+1}}a_nx^n. $$
Comparing the coefficient of $x^n$ gives
$$ a_n=\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{(n+1)2^{n+1}}a_n. $$
Clearly if $n\ge 2$, $\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{(n+1)2^{n+1}}\neq1$
and hence one must have $a_n=0$ for $n=2,3,4,\cdots$. So
$$ f(x)=a_1x. $$

But a $C^\infty$ function is not necessarily representable as a power series.

Let me think about it.
